# Rule of thumb - number of predictors - Poisson regression rates

Tags: regression, poisson-distribution, predictor, rule-of-thumb

I am interested in estimating a Poisson regression for mortality rates, with number of deaths as the dependent variable and log(population size) as the offset. I have 50 observations (states).

I am aware of rules of thumbs in various regression models to figure out the maximum number of predictors. For example:
Cox model: at least 5 events per predictor,
logistic regression: at least 5 observations where Y=1 per predictor
*etc*...

Is there a similar rule of thumb for Poisson models?

Comment: ¿Why do you need "a rule of thumb"? Those are mainly, anyway, just meant as some yardstick people can use until they get experience!  Just do some simulations in R and find out four yourself ...  Anyway, in Poisson regression the dependent variable $Y$ is a count, so a numeric variable, so as a start you could use the same rules you would apply for ordinary linear regression... The main difference between those two models is __not__ in the distributional assumption (Normal versus Poisson), but in the structure of the expectation --- linear versus multiplicative.